# How to use regex match if the string contains user-defined command for emoticon

Tags: php, regex

I am creating an application and I'm making command for emoticons.

When you type `/happy` it displays icon. I already did that.

But what I want is if the user types `/happy happy` it would display the *my emoticon* + *happy* word.

How to do this using regex? Another example:

User inputs: `/happy /happy /happy happy`

There should be 3 emoticons and 1 word.

Comment: `str_replace('/happy','<img src="happy.png"/>',$text)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you don't even need a regex for this, but if you wanted to use one, it's as simple as:

```
$string = preg_replace('@/happy\b@i', ':)', $string);
```

The `\b` is a "word boundary" which would prevent "`/happyer`" from turning into `:)er`.

Comment: i'm not trying to prevent /happy to an :) cause /happy should be converted into :)  icon. But what i want if I type /happy happy it would display :) icon + happy string

Comment: You can replace the ":)" I used with anything you want--an image, or `&#9786;`, or whatever you want!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `/` in your regex, so you match words that have it, like this:

```
$output = preg_replace('~/happy~', 'EMOTICON', $input);
```

For example:

```
$input = "I'm so /happy now!";
$output = preg_replace('~/happy~', "&#9786;", $input);
echo $output;

// output: I'm so &#9786; now!
```

> Rendered output: I'm so ☺ now!